# Output text using 'grep' and 'man' with some options

Tags: linux

I need to output all options of command `grep` described in `man`(just keys like `-z` without repetition and description).
I try to do like this:
`grep -o "-z"|man grep`
But it doesn't work as I expected it to be.
So my question is: how to get all `key` options of command `grep` without any description and repetition.

Comment: So, are you looking for `-z` description?

Comment: Find out what you want first.

Comment: I need just keys without description and repeating. It is the main goal of the task. I would be really appreciated if you give me some advice about it.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Please clarify you question.

Comment: But at first, swap your commands on sides of pipeline.

Comment: it seems `-z` is your search text. you can do `[-]z` instead to avoid having grep to take your search text as option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question:

`man grep | grep -o '\-\w\b'`

At first we use `man grep` command and then pipe our output to the `grep` command using regular expression `grep -o '\-\w\b'`.

> `-o option` - shows only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN
>
> `- \w option` - matches any single "word" character, namely alphanumeric or underscore. This is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Conversely, capital `\W` means "any non-word character".
>
> `- \b option` - means "word boundary", which is like an anchor because it doesn't consume any characters.